# How many prime numbers are between two consecutive square numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given two consecutive square numbers, a and b. Is there a method where we can determine how many prime numbers are between them.

Comment: There is the answer given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2425244/estimating-the-number-of-primes-between-two-consecutive-squares-from-the-product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a difficult question to answer. Legendre's conjecture states that there is at least one prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ for all $n$; it is still unsolved. So it is unlikely a method exists at the moment.

Comment: Of course an obvious method exists: Perform trial division on all candidates